# Regex cannot match any character inside quotes

Tags: regex

I cant seem to get the following regex to match. I'm having a problem with matching whats inside the {}

The regex is:

```
\{([\s\w|'.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(.*\*\d+)
```

And the string to match is this:

```
value=subarray({'1*MyVar'}, EXCEL.x*48, 1)
value=subarray({'1/MyVar'}, EXCEL.x*48, 1)
value=subarray({'1--MyVar'}, EXCEL.x*48, 1)
value=subarray({'90000'}, EXCEL.x*48, 1)
value=subarray({'Holy Moly'}, EXCEL.x*48, 1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/frF0eC/3

The first 3 do not match, but the last 2 do match. Any idea how to get them to all match? Instead of using \w do I have to explicitly match all possible characters?

Comment: your input has various special characters like `\-` which aren't  covered by this `[\s\w|'.,]`

Comment: Hi Pavneet, any idea how I would match them?

Answer (score 1):

This covers it

```
\{([\S| \|'.,]*)},\s*(\p{L}+)(.*\*\d+)
```